# MySQL Access Control List

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, diagram, class-diagram

I am trying to implement a site where patients can access medical records. My problem is where the clinicians have access to the records. So they should only be able to view the patient's record if they are on an Access Control List which states which doctors can view the patient's record. The question that I have is what type of relationship will the clinicians have to the access control list; would it be many to one, many to many, etc.? Also I am not entirely sure about the foreign keys.

This is my image of what I think it would look like, any help would be awesome.
[image]

Comment: It should be many-to-many. Each patient allows multiple clinicians to access their records, and each clinician has access to multiple patients. Use a relationship table that lists the patient ID and clinician ID.

Comment: It appears to me the `AccessList` just needs to have the `IdClinician` instead of the PK's from `AccessList` being on the `Clinician.`  Does a Patient have 0 or many medical records?  Does an Access list denote which patient and/or medical records a clinician has access to?  It looks like to me the Access List is the associative table between `MedicalRecords` `clinician` and `patient`.    I'm unsure why patient has medical records as the FK... wouldn't the record list the patient?  or is it a medical record associates to one and only one patient and a patient only has 1 medical record?

Comment: Just a note: Weight, height, insurance provider, policy can all vary over time.  So to me you have static information such as bloodType which vs information that does change based on date/time measured.  So  the carnality of the data in Medicalrecords is suspect to me. this leads me to question other relationships making this a question I don't think anyone can answer.

Comment: For many-to-many mapping tables, follow the tips [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for performance.

Comment: @xQbert I am just going to assume that a patient has one record. And the access list denotes which clinicians have access to the patient's medical record, so clinicians should be able to be added or removed. Because of this, wouldn't the list need both the IdClinician and the Id Patient, so that the list knows who it belongs to?

Comment: @xQbert and yes the medical record is a single entity that belongs to the patient. So because of this, it should contain the FK of the patient right? and the patient should not have a FK to the record? Sorry, it has been a couple years since I have worked with databases

Comment: @xQbert I am assuming that all information is static, and the only data that changes will be the access control list which would either add or remove clinicians that have access to the record.

Comment: If we assume: patient is 1:1 w/ medical, patient is 1:M w/ access list clinician is 1:M w/ access list, and medical has no needed relation to AccessList.  Then Access List should just have PatientID and ClinicianID; and to me patientID belongs in Medical not medical in patient; and AccessList and PatientRecords do not belong in Clinician

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues:**

1. I don't see why you have both patient and medical records on the access list. (if 1:1 patient medical record)
2. I don't see why you have accessList info on Clinician.  This means that a clinician can only have access to 1 access list? seems wrong.

Question:

- Are you trying to setup the data so that you have ACL groups you assign a patient to a "group" and all Clinician's part of that group then have access so you don't have to manage the individual Patient Clinician associations?  If so we need a ACL_GROUP table and Clinician's should be assigned to a group; or you need a Hierarchy within your ACL table.

How I'd likely setup the data with the information to date:

### Patient

- idPatient             (PK)

### Medicalrecords

- idMedicalrecord       (PK)
- Patient_idPatient     (FK to patient)

### Clinician

- idClinician        (PK)

### AccessList

- idAccessList          (PK)
- AccessListName        (Group name or patient Name)
- Patient_idPatient     (FK to patient)  (COMPOSITE UNIQUE INDEX1)
- Clinician_idClinician (Fk to Clinician) (COMPOSITE UNIQUE INDEX1)
- IdAccessList_Parent   (Maybe... FK to AccessList_IDAccessList) used to manage "security groups")

This allows the following:

1. A patient record could have 1:M Medical records
2. A medical record associates to 1 and only 1 patient
3. A clinician may have access to a patient and all their medical history; but not specific medical records if multiple.  If you need to limit access to certain patient medical information then instead of having the accessList join to Patient, have it join to MedicalRecords; thereby allowing to you to limit to specific medical inforamtion; or keep both allowing access
   to the whole patient; or specific medical records if multiple exist.

Answer (score 0):

The `AccessList` table represents the many-to-many relationship between patients in the `Patient` table and clinicians in the `Clinician` table. Thus one clinician from the `Clinician` table will appear many times in the `AccessList` table because they will have access to many patients' records, i.e. it's a one-to-many relationship between those tables. The same is true of patients from the `Patient` table having possibly several clinicians, i.e. a one-to-many relationship to the `AccessList` table. Thus there should be foreign keys in the `AccessList` table to `idPatient` from the `Patient` table and `idClinician` from the `Clinician` table.